# How to unlock Kendo-UI Grid multi-column header programmatically

Tags: printing, kendo-ui, locking, kendo-grid, multiple-columns

I have a grid with multi-column headers and there is a group column A which is locked. Here is the code:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columns = [
            {
                title: "A", locked: true, headerAttributes: { "class": "section-border" }, groupId : "A",
                columns: [{ field: "ROW_HEADER", filterable: false, width: "20px", title: "   .", sortable: false, locked: true, headerAttributes: { "class": "sub-col darkYellow-col rowHeaderHeadYellow", "style": "border-right: 0px !important;" }, attributes: { "class": "contert-alpha  rowHeaderCell" } },
                          { field: "COLUMN1", title: "COLUMN1", width: "80px", hidden: true, locked: true, headerAttributes: { "class": "sub-col darkYellow-col rowHeaderHead2" }, attributes: { "class": "" }, template: "#: COLUMN1)#" },
                          { field: "COLUMN2", title: "COLUMN2", width: "150px", locked: true, headerAttributes: { "class": "sub-col darkYellow-col rowHeaderHead2" }, attributes: { "class": "" }, template: #:COLUMN2#}
                          ]
            },
            {
                title: "B", headerAttributes: { "class": "section-border" }, groupId: "B",
                columns: [{ field: "COLUMN3", title: "COLUMN3", width: "110px", headerAttributes: { "class": "sub-col continuity" }, attributes: { "class": "contert-alpha center-middle" }, template: "#: COLUMN3 #" },
                          { field: "COLUMN4", title: "COLUMN4", width: "120px", headerAttributes: { "class": "sub-col no-left-border" }, attributes: { "class": "contert-number " }, format: "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}" },
                           }]
            }]
```

I want to unlock the group column A programmatically before printing the grid so that it appears as one grid instead of two. I have set locked=false for COLUMN1, COLUMN2 and group column A before printing but it still stays locked. Then I've set only group column A as unlocked before printing and the group still stays locked. I am using recursive method to unlock them but I but in order to show the gist of this functionality I am doing this to unlock:

```
thisGrid.unlockColumn("A");thisGrid.unlockColumn("ROW_HEADER");thisGrid.unlockColumn("COLUMN1");thisGrid.unlockColumn("COLUMN2");
```

Where thisGrid is instance of above grid. If anyone has programmatically locked/unlocked multi-column header please help. Thanks

Comment: What is thisGrid? Where is it set?  How/where are you trying to apply the unlock?  Is it on a button click?

Comment: Actually I've found its solution which I'm posting as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are unlocking columns we have to make sure that there is atleast one column left in the grid which is still locked. So in my case I removed ROW_HEADER from the group A and put it independently as the first column, now when I try to unlock column group A it get successfully unlocked.

```
$scope.gridOptions.columns = [{ field: "ROW_HEADER", filterable: false, width: "20px", title: "   .", sortable: false, locked: true, headerAttributes: { "class": "sub-col darkYellow-col rowHeaderHeadYellow", "style": "border-right: 0px !important;" }, attributes: { "class": "contert-alpha  rowHeaderCell" } },
        {
            title: "A", locked: true, headerAttributes: { "class": "section-border" }, groupId : "A", field: "DUMMY_FIELD"
            columns: [
                      { field: "COLUMN1", title: "COLUMN1", width: "80px", hidden: true, locked: true, headerAttributes: { "class": "sub-col darkYellow-col rowHeaderHead2" }, attributes: { "class": "" }, template: "#: COLUMN1)#" },
                      { field: "COLUMN2", title: "COLUMN2", width: "150px", locked: true, headerAttributes: { "class": "sub-col darkYellow-col rowHeaderHead2" }, attributes: { "class": "" }, template: #:COLUMN2#}
                      ]
        },
        {
            title: "B", headerAttributes: { "class": "section-border" }, groupId: "B",
            columns: [{ field: "COLUMN3", title: "COLUMN3", width: "110px", headerAttributes: { "class": "sub-col continuity" }, attributes: { "class": "contert-alpha center-middle" }, template: "#: COLUMN3 #" },
                      { field: "COLUMN4", title: "COLUMN4", width: "120px", headerAttributes: { "class": "sub-col no-left-border" }, attributes: { "class": "contert-number " }, format: "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}" },
                       }]
        }]
```

Another issue is that there is no field property defined in grouped column A but we need to either have field property or column index to lock/unlock a column, so I've added `field: "DUMMY_FIELD"` there and then unlock it successfuly using this code: `thisGrid.unlockColumn("DUMMY_FIELD")`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order for the `unlockColumn` method to work on the A column group you need to assign it a field property.

The problem is that the Kendo UI Grid documentation states that after initializing the grid with a locked column, at least one column should remain locked at all times.

In your case, You have two main "columns", A and B, and only A is locked.
Therefore when you try to unlock A, it stays locked.

One workaround is to add another column with a zero width and keep it locked at all times.

See a demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bXY8VB1zzW4F86op6PSw?p=preview).